# Can I run du to get disk usage on directories I don't own without sudo?

Tags: linux, disk-usage

I need to run `du` on `/home` on a shared machine where I don't have sudo. Someone has filled up the partition and I'd like to track them down without the hoopla of contacting IT.

Is it possible to get disk usage in this case without `sudo` access? `du --max-depth=1 /home` just gets rebuked with permission denied.

I'm wondering if there's another option.

Comment: What would be the point of permissions?

Comment: But of course to keep *other* people from snooping around, not me... :) I had to ask though, you never know if there's some trick lurking out there that might, perhaps, at least summarize that which you cannot touch.

Comment: <helpful=not> ISTR Multics did provide something much like that -- but Multics was designed when one disk drive was the size of a washing machine and cost more than a car </>